# Load balance Kafka consumer multiple instances

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, apache-kafka, load-balancing, kafka-consumer-api

I have a consumer that reads and writes messages to a time-series database. We have multiple instances of the time series database running as a cluster on multiple physical machines.

Our plan is to deploy the consumer on Kubernetes so I can scale if I need more instance with load-balance they all point to a single time series service that is running.

Now I getting an Issue where it's come to my mind that if I have 5 instances which consume the same topic then they work individually means( **they all get message payload and save like any one instance is doing** )

***What we want is***

we want if one consumer is busy then it will go to the next free instance but not be subscribed to by all instance running. To scale or load-balance means I want like normal load-balancing application or how spring-boot app works when you scale on Kubernetes

so is there any way to make it like a load-balancing consumer and processing only one, even consume by 1st or 2nd or 3rd like normal app work as loadbanlacer?

if anyone has ideas about this, how it going to behave and what kind of output we are going to get if doing this with Kafka Spring boot application?

Comment: are you deploying the consumers with auto generated consumer group id? Seems that each one has its own consumer group, so they act independently

Comment: @aran how you saying they auto generted consumer group id if i have mention in code

Comment: @aran tell me one think if they work independently what they benefit  to scale it or load-balancing

Comment: you won't balance the load if each of your consumers has its own consumer group, as the second consumer won't help the first one, but start consuming and processing the same messages the first one processed, from the beginning. so you'll be processing each message twice (and if a third consumer comes in, thrice, and so on)

Comment: so is  there any way to make it like a load-balancing consumer  and processing only one even by 1st or 2nd or 3rd like normal app work as loadbanlacer

Comment: Side note: what you want is exactly what Kafka Connect offers... Not sure what database you're using, but there's an InfluxDb sink already available that works well

Comment: @cricket_007 i am using postgres with timescaledb extension

Comment: Checkout the docs https://docs.timescale.com/v1.3/using-timescaledb/ingesting-data#postgresqls-kafka-connector

Comment: @cricket_007 if am using kafka connector it will work like load balance for me

Comment: Actually, that links to getting data from Postgres to Kafka. What you want, though, is just the JDBC sink connector https://debezium.io/blog/2017/09/25/streaming-to-another-database/ (just focus on the Postgres connection part)

Comment: Kafka Connect will distribute tasks per partition of the input topics just like any other consumer group. This is built in the Kafka protocol no matter what API / tool you choose

Comment: but this case i have to directly send to db or will i able to make any change in payload message that i consume from Kafka

Comment: Kafka Connect mostly assumes that your input exactly matches what you want in the output system. If you need to make major adjustments, you would create an intermediate, processed and filtered, topic. The main point being that interacting with external systems other than Kafka using plain consumer, is that you can lose delivery guarantees